# What's the correct way to type-hint a method that returns an instance of it's own class?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to make Foo into an immutable object. When I 'extend' foo I want to get a new instance of Foo. I'd expect to type-hint it something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def extend(self, item:str) -> Foo:
        pass
```

This looks right, but IntelliJ doesn't agree. I get a red underline underneath Foo on the 2nd line. The error message is: **Unresolved Reference 'Foo'**.

I sort of get what's it's saying: At the tyme we are parsing line 2 we don't yet have the object Foo, so the interpreter doesn't know what Foo means.

But oddly enough, this very unsatisfying alternative is good enough for PyCharm (but invalid python):

```
class Foo(object):
    def extend(self, item:str) -> Foo_:
        pass

Foo_ = Foo
```

So is there a valid way to do this? How do I say in a type-hint annotation that a particular method returns a new instance of self.**class**?

I'm using Python 3.5 on a very recent version of IntelliJ with PyCharm plugins.